# Google Custom Search - Refinements

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

I have a Google Custom Search I'm using for a site I'm working on (the search is restricted to this one site). As part of the results you can specify "refinements". These refinements appear as tabs but I want them to appear as links. I do not see anyway to control this nor do I find anything in the docs about how to control this. Anyone have any experience with this?

On Google's own examples they appear as links, like so: http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/customsearch/images/refine_treatment.png

However all I can get are tabs, like so:
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_HUb2ygrQR50/TCHcpRiZS8I/AAAAAAAAEPc/m9R1yA2lZaw/s1600/SupportLineRefinement.png

How can I control this?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I do not think it is possible to do this. I think the tabs are your only option.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you see links in the google example, is because it's the old version, similar to the iframe option. You're using the new search element.

As far as making them into links, not hard to do using some CSS with !important, to make them look like links.